# Depend Repository Interface in Domain to view model in Application contract Layer in Onion Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mapping, onion-architecture

My Question is Can We Depend Repository Interface in Domain to
view model in Application contract Layer in Onion Architecture ,
i need Mapping My model to view model , but i don't need all field,
can i depend the interface of repository model in domain to view model in Application contract Layer ?

```
using P.Domain.ArticleCategoryAgg;
namespace P.Domain.ArticleAgg;
public class Article
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string title{get;set;}
  public string content{get;set;}
}
```

---

the orginal article repository is like below

```
namespace P.Domain.ArticleAgg;
public interface IArticleRepository
 {
 public List<Article> GetAll();
 void Add(Article entity);
 Article Getby(long id);
 void Save();
}
```

---

```
    using P.Application.Contracts.Article;
    namespace P.Domain.ArticleAgg;
    public interface IArticleRepository
    {
     public List<ArticleViewModel> GetAll();
     void Add(Article entity);
     Article Getby(long id);
     void Save();
    }
```

---

if you see the code you will understand i depending my repository interface depend on view Model in application.contract , i Want To know this is a correct way to mapping article model to view model ?
if my question unclear tell me to refactoring my question

Comment: Why you need Map model to View model? If you don't need all field, you can just put the field whitch you need into view model. Can you explain your qurestion in more details?

Comment: sometime i need some field but if return all field then i most return a list full of result its mean i need select more field and it's make my query into database bigger and my Application Become slower , for this reason I Created A View Model Then Get the Data I Want From Database , in this way I Can set constrain before send query to database

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use viewModel to avhieve this.